# PageRank denotes how many inputs a node has from influential nodes (directed form of eigenvector). Is there a metric for outputs to influential nodes?

Tags: networks, social-network, pagerank

PageRank is the directed form of eigenvector centrality, denoting how influential a node is in terms of indegree edges. Is there an outdegree version?

PageRank assumes that “ important nodes are those that have many in-links from important pages or important other nodes.”

“ PageRank measures the transitive (or directional) influence of nodes and is a variant of the Eigenvector Centrality algorithm. Eigenvector Centrality can be used on undirected graphs, whereas the PageRank algorithm is more suited to directed graphs.”

In other words, PageRank is a directed generalization/application of eigenvector centrality and reflects how many inputs a node has from influential nodes. But is there an analogous metric for how many outputs or outdegrees a node has to influential nodes? If PageRank is indegree focused, could you measure or calculate an outdegree focused eigenvector centrality generalization? I cannot seem to find such a metric